# Probability of getting same value in dice throwing infinite number of times

Tags: probability

While throwing a dice infinite number of times, what is the probability that the same value will come infinite number of times?

eg. 3, 3, 3, 3, 3...

I tried to calculate it as shown below and got $0$.

Probability of x equal to 3 is $1/6$

Probability of x equal to 3 infinite times is $(1/6)^\infty$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1/6)^n =0$

Is this right or the probability will be always non zero?

Comment: Are you seeking the probability of having every roll equal 3? That would be $0$. Or the probability of infinitely many 3's? That would be $1$, since that could FAIL to happen only if some tail of the sequence contains no 3's, which would have probability less than $(5/6)^n$ for all $n$, i.e. $0$.

Comment: As an aside $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^n$ is certainly *not* equal to zero... It is after all $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{198}+\dots > \frac{1}{6}>0$.  It is not clear what you *think* this summation represents in relation to your problem, but it at a glance is irrelevant.

Comment: @JMoravitz, sorry I messed up there. I wanted to add limit notation instead of sum.

Comment: @Ned 
I wanted to calculate probability of having every roll equal 3.
So if I understood correctly it will be 0 as you says.

Answer (score 1):

To argue more carefully, let $A$ be the event that every roll is a $3$, and let $A_n$ be the event that each of the first $n$ rolls is a $3$. Then 
 $P(A_n)=(\frac16)^n$, as you've calculated. But event $A$ implies event $A_n$, so $P(A)\le P(A_n)$ for every $n$. Conclude that $P(A)=0$. Argue similarly for the other values $1,2,4,5,6$.